# Getting error in input-group-addon when validating the field using ajax and jquery in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**Now its been 46 day's till i am stuck with this. Or there is Another way to Do this.**

I Know This very simple But How can i wrap input-group under form-group. I am  submitting  the form data in codeigniter using ajax and showing validation errors. 
The issue is that input-group-addon wraps to the next line underneath the form field when the error control is added by Jquery Validate.

[image]

**Controller**

```
function infoValidation() {
        $result = array('status' => false, 'message' => array());

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">','</div>');
        if ($this->form_validation->run('company_registration')) {

                $result['status'] = true;

        }else {

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

                $result['message'][$key] = form_error($key);
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

**view**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>
        <input type = "text" name="creditCardNumber" class="form-control input-md" id="creditCardNumber" placeholder="Mobile No">
    </div>
</div>
```

**ajax**

I have also try to append the element But Nothing Happens

```
$.ajax({
        url : me.attr('action'),
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'POST',
        data : me.serialize(),
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            if (resp.status == true) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');

                $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
                $(".text-danger").remove();
            }else {
                $('#msg').html('<div class="well"><h5>Please Check Your Details</h5></div>');
                $.each(resp.message, function(key, value) {

                    var element = $("#"+key);
                        element.closest('div.form-group, div.input-group')
                               .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                               .find('.text-danger').remove();

                        element.after(value);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the jQuery validate plugin method in order to get compatibility with bootstrap.

```
Refer http://jsfiddle.net/mapb_1990/hTPY7/7/
```

Example code

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So How can i validate my fields with codeigniter validation rules ,

Answer (score 0):

Just add label for error at your desired location:

**<label for="creditCardNumber" generated="true" class="error">**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>
    <input type = "text" name="creditCardNumber" class="form-control input-md" id="creditCardNumber" placeholder="Mobile No">
  </div>
 <label for="creditCardNumber" generated="true" class="error"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Govind - and simple!
This also solves the problem of using **jquery validation** with **Bootstrap form input groups**; it allows you to place the error message AFTER the ***whole*** input group, so that the message doesn't split the input group.
For example, when using a hide/reveal password icon that you want to stay on the same form line as the input.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputPassword"  class="form-label">Password</label>
     <div class="input-group mb-3">
         <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password...." required class="form-control" />
         <span class="input-group-text" role="button" title="view password" id="passBtn">
             <i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
      </div>
      <label for="inputPassword" generated="true" class="error"></label>
 </div>
```